# How to stop R Loop storing the same variable multiple times instead of just once

Tags: r, loops, subset

I have time-series daily temperature data which I've split into years and seasons (SU = Summer etc.). The Season.Year column allows for analysis of the climatological year (using December from the previous year as winter, keeping the seasonality of the trend).

Sample:

```
    Day Month Year maxtp Season.Year Season
1   20  8   2007    19.1    2007       SU
2   21  8   2007    17.6    2007       SU
3   22  8   2007    21.8    2007       SU
4   23  8   2007    20.0    2007       SU
5   24  8   2007    22.4    2007       SU
6   25  8   2007    21.2    2007       SU
7   26  8   2007    19.3    2007       SU
8   27  8   2007    17.5    2007       SU
9   28  8   2007    18.9    2007       SU
10  29  8   2007    18.3    2007       SU
11  30  8   2007    19.5    2007       SU
12  1   9   2007    19.8    2007       A
13  2   9   2007    19.2    2007       A
14  3   9   2007    18.9    2007       A
15  4   9   2007    20.4    2007       A
16  5   9   2007    21.2    2007       A
```

I want to extract all the winters from each year, creating a subset (and new dataset) with all the temperature values from winter 2007 to 2014.

The R-Loop I created (below) does this, but repeats the data (i.e. there are 364 values for winter (W) 2008 where there should only be around 90)

```
for( i in 2008:2014) {

  for(j in 1:4) { 

    j = 1

    data.sub <- subset(data, data$Season.Year == i & data$Season == s[j])

    Winter <- rbind(Winter, data.sub)

  }

}
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with this loop? Why is the subset storing so much data, and not just giving me all winter values for 2008, followed by 2009, up to 2014?

There should be around 90 data points for each winter for each year (around 600 values overall, whereas I'm getting over 2500).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problems are coming from modifying `j` within the inner loop, so for each of the four values of `j`, you're then extracting the `s[1]` data.

Regardless, it should be simpler to just do:

```
Winter <- subset(data, data$Season.Year %in% 2008:2014 & data$Season %in% s[1])
```

presuming that s[1] is winter

Comment: This is much cleaner and works perfectly, thanks a lot!